# How to identify sns.pairplot with .groupby variable?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am trying to place the legend on a pairplot but keep having trouble using the variable "grupo". I want the data to be colored according to this variable in the end.

Everything seems to be working fine up until the end. Also, numeric variables are working fine for the pairplot, I did a test with "UXValor".

Any ideas what could be wrong? Thanks a lot!

```
#Only keep columns needed.
df = df[['grupo', 'UXValor', 'impactoValor', 'usoValor', 'implementaciónValor', 'valorDeFormato']]
df.head()
```

[image]

```
df_group = df.groupby('grupo').agg(
    UXValor=('UXValor', sum),
    impactoValor=('impactoValor', sum),
    #usoValor=('usoValor', sum),
    implementacionValor=('implementaciónValor', sum),
    valorDeFormato=('valorDeFormato', sum)
)   
df_group.head()
```

[image]

```
#Create the default pairplot
sns.pairplot(df_group, hue = "UXValor")
```

[image]

Comment: `KeyError: 'grupo'`: `grupo` is the name of the index. Either add `as_index=False` inside `groupby('grupo', as_index=False)` or do `df_group = df_group.reset_index()`.

Comment: I tried both. With as_index=False I get this:

`level_0, index, UXValor, impactoValor, implementacionValor, valorDeFormato
0, 0 0, 4.63, 5.95, 6.95, 4.14
1, 1, 1, 6.61, 7.94, 10.30, 9.57
2, 2, 2, 1.65, 3.00, 2.66, 1.98
3, 3, 3, 2.64, 3.98, 1.98, 2.98
4, 4 4, 0.66, 0.33, 0.33, 0.43`

And later I get the same error.

Comment: And with .reset_index() I do get a dataframe that resembles this:  `grupo, UXValor impactoValor, implementacionValor, valorDeFormato
0, Null, 4.63, 5.95, 6.95, 4.14
1, Actividades de Integrantes, 6.61, 7.94, 10.30, 9.57 ` But still same error. Any ideas on what could I be messing up? @QuangHoang

Comment: Altough both do change the structure of the dataframe in a way it seems that should work both still display the same error. I think the dataframe is missing the "grupo" column. Any way to include it in the .agg() (even though they are strings) so it is part of the new dataframe?